# Cordova : writing in a file

Tags: json, cordova

There is something i've been stuck for quite some time, despite me searching on numerous forums. I'm sorry if my english is not perfect, I hope I'm clear enough for you to be able to understand me and help me get through this.

I'm trying to learn some mobile development with Cordova.
I want to create an application instagram-like, in which memories will be stored. The application uses two pages :
- a page displaying all stored memories ;
- a page adding a memory. Memories are stored in a local json file.

Here is my code (for now) :
*note : the code has been translated for better comprehension. I hope I didn"t make any translation error, unrelated to the topic at hand*

**addMemory.html (view to add a memory)**

```
<form role="form" class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title :</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" ng-model="souvenir.title" placeholder="Add a memory title" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="image">Image :</label>
        <button id="image" class="form-control btn btn-default">Add...</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="createMemory()">Create</button>
</form>
```

**addMemoryController.js** *(add a memory. For now, a memory is a static json stored in a local file. Dynamic control will be added later on)*

```
app.controller("addMemoryController", function ($scope, $location) {
  //Array of all stored memories
  $scope.memoriesList = [];

  //New memory to add (for now static)
  $scope.memory = {
      image: "image/moutain.png",
      title:""
  }

  //The function pushes the new memory into the list then save the array
  $scope.createMemory = function () {
      $scope.memoriesList.push($scope.memory);
      $scope.saveArray();
  }

  //The function save the array into the local file
  $scope.saveArray = function () {
      window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
      var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*10; // 10MB
      navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
          requestedBytes,
          function (grantedBytes) {
              window.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, grantedBytes, $scope.fileSystemReceived, $scope.errorHandler('requestFileSystem'));
          },
          $scope.errorHandler
      );
      $location.path("/");
  }

  //Function called when the fileSystem is received
  $scope.fileSystemReceived = function (fileSystem) {
      fileSystem.root.getFile("memories.json", { create: true, exclusive: false }, $scope.fileEntryReceived, $scope.errorHandler('getFile'));
  }

  //Function called when the fileEntry is received
  $scope.fileEntryReceived = function (fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.createWriter($scope.fileWriterReceived, $scope.errorHandler('createWriter'));
  }

  //Function called when the fileWriter is received
  $scope.fileWriterReceived = function (fileWriter) {
      fileWriter.onwrite = function (evt) {
          console.log("write success");
      };
      var memoriesListText = angular.toJson($scope.memoriesList);
      fileWriter.write(memoriesListText);

  }

  //Error managment
  $scope.errorHandler = function (errorMessage) {
      return function () { console.log(errorMessage); };
  }
});
```

When I launch my application, I get an error with the "write" function :
*TypeMismatchError: The type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object.*

I tried to write a simple text content without any difference :

```
fileWriter.write("some text");
```

I even tried to create a ".txt" file, logically without any difference.

What am I supposed to give as parameter if not a text ? I can't file a doc describing this function type signature.

Comment: Just a question: Why don't you use local storage or sqlite?

Comment: Well, I would like to use the local storage. It seems the demonstration I use is rather old and not up to date. As for the sqlite, I first plan on knowing how to use a maximum of cordiva plugins. Could you tell me what I should change to use the localFileSystem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filewriter expects an object, so call it like:

```
var blob = new Blob(["some text"], {type: "text/plain"});
fileWriter.write(blob);
```

More informations:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

If you are searching for infos about cordova, start at cordova itself at: http://cordova.apache.org Read the docs and the blog. There are a lot of out dated infos in the internet.